# Passing proper variable in popup modal in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I have a popup modal for editing the rows created by fetching data from database. I am creating a popup modal for edit purpose. While clicking the edit button, only the data of the top-most row shows up. '**modaleditsubtask**' is my edit modal. and It should show up once I click the **edit** button. And in within this popup modal, value of the respective row should show up, not the one at the top. I couldn't figure it out what went wrong in the code.

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container" id="default_container_style">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            @foreach ($tasks as $tasks) 
            {{$tasks->name}}
          </div>

          {{$tasks->task_description}}

          <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped task-table ">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Name</th>
                       <th></th>

                       <th></th>
                       <th></th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                @foreach ($subtask_pending as $subtask)

                <tr>
                    <td> {{$subtask->name}} </td>

                <td>
                  <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" class=" subtaskeditclass btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-target="#modaleditsubtask">
                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-edit"></i>Edit
                  </button>

                </td>
                <td>
                 <form action="/subtaskdelete/{{ $subtask->id }}" method="POST" style="display: inline-block;">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

                  <button type="submit" id="delete-task-{{$subtask->id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>Delete
                  </button>
                </form>
              </td>

            </tr>
            <form action="/subtask/edit/{{$subtask->id}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">

             <div class="modal fade" id="modaleditsubtask" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header" id="popupwindow_subtask">
                    <b class="modal-title" >Edit Name</b>      
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>                                
                  </div>
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                  <div class=subtask1_row_style>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">New Name</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" name="name" id="task-name" class="form-control" value="{{$subtask->name}}">         
                    </div>                                      
                  </div> 
                  </div>                                   
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" id="{{ $subtask->id }}" class="btn btn-info">
                      <i class="fa fa-btn fa-edit"></i>Edit
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </form>
        @endforeach
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  @endsection
```

Comment: you are giving same `id` to every modal. Try giving different id like `modaleditsubtask1` `modaleditsubtask2` etc.

Comment: Thank you but I think we should have same modal to every Ids, as we can have any number of rows and each of the rows will have edit button which on clicked will show up that modal.

Comment: Yes there should a sing modal. But in your case you are print modals for every row.

Comment: Yes, there should be a single modal. How can I correct it so that there will be single modal but appropriate value will show up in it ?

Comment: This- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target can be helpfull